# Is there a way to make the significant values in the heatmap more visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I'm working with 2190 rows of somewhat large data. Using three variables—I'm trying to plot a heatmap. But instead of a heatmap, it shows me some meaningless scattered points. Is there a way to increase the effect or power of the little scattered points?

```
data=pd.read_csv('L0.csv')
X=data.X
Y=data.Y
Z=data.Z
data=data.pivot_table(index="Y",columns="X",values="Z") 
data=np.nan_to_num(data)
plt.grid(False)
plt.imshow(data, extent =[0, 15, -5, 3], origin = 'lower', cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.show()
```

I'm getting this heatmap:

[image: current output]

But I want to get a heatmap like:

[image: expected output]

Comment: use the `vmin, vmax` arguments, of imshow, basically pass the min and max of data.Z to them.

Comment: Without data it is hard to tell what's going on.  Maybe you can add `plt.hist(data.ravel())` to give an impression of how the data looks like? You could also try to transform your data, e.g. `plt.imshow(np.exp(data), ...)`.  Note that using the same name for your input data and the result of the pivot table makes your code harder to read and to reason about.